# Convert list of lists of string into floats

Tags: python, string, list, floating-accuracy

I have a list of lists, that every list contains a string. I want to convert every string in the list to float numbers. Instead of having one element in the list ( a string ), I want my list to contain multiple floats

```
 [['1,10,300,0.5,85'],
  ['3,16,271,2.9,89'],...
```

To:

```
[[1,10,300,0.5,85],
 [3,16,271,2.9,89],...
```

How can i do it? 
Thank you

Comment: each sub-list would only contain one string?

Comment: How do you do it for one string? `list(map(float, string.split(',')))` and now do this inside a loop for each string.

Comment: try `result = [list(ast.literal_eval(x[0])) for x in [['1,10,300,0.5,85'],  ['3,16,271,2.9,89']]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = [['1,10,300,0.5,85'], ['3,16,271,2.9,89']]

y = [[float(v) for v in r[0].split(',')] for r in x]
```

`y` will be

```
[[1.0, 10.0, 300.0, 0.5, 85.0], [3.0, 16.0, 271.0, 2.9, 89.0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

a solution using python evaluation:

```
import ast

result = [list(ast.literal_eval(x[0])) for x in [['1,10,300,0.5,85'],  ['3,16,271,2.9,89']]]

>>> result
[[1, 10, 300, 0.5, 85], [3, 16, 271, 2.9, 89]]
```

`ast.literal_eval` will yield `tuple` because the quoted data has no brackets, so convert to `list` if needed, else leave as-is

(what bothers me, though, is why the inner list has only one element)